# dplyr arrange by reverse alphabetical order

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm curious why the arrange function won't will work for alphabetical order but not reverse alphabetical order.

```
df <- data.frame(string = as.character(c("b", "a", "c")), stringsAsFactors = F) 

df %>% arrange(string) #works

df %>% arrange(-string) #does not work
```

Am I just using the completely wrong method for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: In `?arrange`, there's a `desc()` function you can use. Fyi, if you have a data.table, it does work with your attempt: `library(data.table); setDT(df); df %>% arrange(-string)`, though this is probably a dtplyr bug.

Comment: `-` in `dplyr` generally means "excluding` something, so I think it's better to not use `-` for descending in `arrange`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the `?arrange` help page, use `desc()`

```
df %>% arrange(desc(string))
```