# Invert rows using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I invert the rows of a dataframe/tibble using dplyr? I don't want to [arrange it by a certain variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144143/dplyr-arrange-by-reverse-alphabetical-order), but rather have it just inverted.

I.e. the tibble

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      a b    
  <int> <chr>
1     1 one  
2     2 two  
3     3 three
4     4 four 
5     5 five
```

should become

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      a b    
  <int> <chr>
1     5 five 
2     4 four 
3     3 three
4     2 two  
5     1 one
```

Comment: @jaap You marked this question as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144143/dplyr-arrange-by-reverse-alphabetical-order) which is simply **not true**. Arranging a dataframe by a certain variable is not (necessarily) the same as inverting its rows. I've updated my question (already some time ago) to stress that. Could you please remove the duplicate marking?

Comment: For your conveniance I've added another target which gives an even better illustration on reverting the order of a dataframe. Consequently I'm not going to remove the duplicate mark.

Comment: Ok, the second linked question makes more sense since it actually gives the answer I'm asking for (`arrange(desc(row_number()))`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just `arrange()` by descending `row_number()` like this:

```r
my_tibble %>%
  dplyr::arrange(-dplyr::row_number())
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `desc`

```
my_tibble %>% 
    arrange(desc(row_number()))
```

Or another option is `slice`

```
my_tibble %>%
    slice(rev(row_number()))
```

Or the 'a' column

```
my_tibble %>% 
   arrange(desc(a))
#  a     b
#1 5  five
#2 4  four
#3 3 three
#4 2   two
#5 1   one
```